# A voice changer app for saving security instead of non liberal governments at online calling

Tags: voice, app, exchange

I need to save me or other security some times for two usages (because of some political restrictions and problems via non liberal governments from religious parties or...):

1. when I record the podcast
2. calling for some media like TV or online radios  (live contacts).

So I googled and find this link:

[Can I change my voice into another person's voice through any software as is shown in movies?](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-change-my-voice-into-another-persons-voice-through-any-software-as-is-shown-in-movies)

which described some software like [vocal free](http://www.nchsoftware.com/voicechanger/) or [DJ Voxchanger](http://www.djvoxchanger.com/) which was for IOS or Windows, so I have Linux Mint and Android 6 mobile phone, there was one app ([Girl Prank Voice Changer)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.apkpure.com/girl-prank-voice-changer/com.markfor.newvoice.voicechange&ved=2ahUKEwjDns_XosHlAhXIX8AKHUt8ALgQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1LBPy20nxHJefWZbTbA-By).

So could you say, what is the proper app or software for these usages, which could not be recreating the main sound source?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not going to close-vote this as I think there might be something here, but it's really unclear what you are asking. Can you please review the question and clarify what you need?

Comment: Added more details

Comment: Changing your voice is not going to be enough: - when you place a podcast online, it's usually traceable to you; - phone calls are traceable as well.

Answer (score 1):

OK so I would tend to approach this with a number of different plugins and functions, typically using pitch and formant change, bit-crushing, modulation. I would tend not to want to approach this with a single plugin as it would be easier for the powers-that-be to be able to reverse-engineer the sound. If you are creating a unique approach to this it will be harder to undo the effect.

Comment: Thanks for your information, so is there any module like python or ... Which be able running online during call to combine and ...

Comment: not that I am aware of.

Comment: MacOS has a tool called MenuBus which might assist you - this will allow you to use plugins on the normal operating system audio bus.